# Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors...SSIS VS2005 Business Development Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

When developing SSIS package using VS 2005, I set up the connection manager for oledb teradata provider and added a oledb source and destination. For oledb source, I used the data access mode as sql command and added sql command text. But when I tried to do column mapping, I'm getting an error message which is detailed below.

Error at All Transactions [OLEDB Source [1627]]:

```
An OLEDB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OLE DB Provider for Teradata"  Hresult: 
0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check 
each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
```

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202009 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
```

---

BUTTONS:

```
OK
```

---

Please let me know why such error throws. I have a workaround which is described as follows.

when you store the sql within `(` and `)` and alias the query and set the data access mode as table name or view name variable, then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Without any more information on the SQL being used in the OLEDB Source component, I can try and guess. Maybe the issue is with the SQL that is returning columns with the same name or similar situation that leads to incorrect metadata.

Comment: My query is fairly simple. It doesn't have any columns. it is a simple select query with all the columns. Still it fails with the above error

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error and I simply edited the provider to a different provider, tested, and then set it back to the original provider.  In my case I was using OLEDB Native client 11 so I set it to 10 and then back to 11.

My guess is the XML got corrupted somehow as my package has been working forever.